# 2 boxes side by side, the second box goes off screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make 2 boxes side by side and in smaller screen the second box goes off screen
like this:
[image]

I want it stay like this until at least 900px width
but the problem when screen be bigger the gap is disappears then expands
https://media.giphy.com/media/33a0O0ra1S3Ou8F7u0/giphy.gif

this is my code

```css
.boxes {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.box {
  width: 820px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}

.box-1 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
}

.box-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 95%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box box-1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="box box-2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: no, in this solution the second box is shrink, I don't want this, I want it to be off screen

Comment: [Edit] your title. Your title and first sentence leads one to believe you have a problem with it being off screen.

Comment: using position absolute for layout purposes is always a bad decision

Answer (score 1):

Could you please specify the reason you're trying to position(absolute) the element here?

As I can see, we can achieve the end result even without positioning.
Note: Here, you've not used the positioning in the correct way.

Another thing, for flexbox, gap works better compared to margin.
Just check the code I've edited, you'll see.

As you want to make the width responsive, giving the width in terms of percentage would be the appropriate option.

```css
.boxes {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box box-1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="box box-2">
    <p>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque.
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a media query to do that. Add this to you CSS :

```
@media all and ( min-width:900px) {
  .box-2 {
     position: relative;
     left: 0;
  }
}
```